# Is use of Leaky ReLu after Batch Normalization (BN) is useful

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

In my CNN network i am using i am using `Leaky ReLu` after `BN` layer. Leaky ReLu solves dying ReLu problem by adding f(y)=ay for negative values. BN introduces zero mean and unit variance. So is BN remove negative part or not i.e. is this converts all valus into 0 to 1 scale? Based on this only selection of Leaky ReLu will be done. Because if BN remove negative part then use of Leaky relu will be same as relu. I am using keras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BN layer tries to zero-mean its output by subtracting an expectation over inputs. So we can expect some of its output values to be negative.

So the LeakyReLU following the BN layer will still receive negative values.

Answer (score 1):

Also, to add to the answer by protagonist, BN actually learns an affine transform ie, it transforms the input to have a mean of alpha (not necessarily 0) and a variance of beta (not necessarily 1) where both alpha and beta are the learnable parameters of the BN layer.